# Steam starts downloading updates while in-game and ignores throttling limit

Tags: steam

I play CS:GO fairly often and that game really requires you to pretty much have a 60 or below ping to be playable. Now, my internet isn't great, but I can usually get that - 30s to 60ish ping range.

However, recently Steam has decided that it is going to ignore my setting for no updates while in-game and my throttling limit that I set!

I'll be paying, and all of a sudden my ping will shoot above 120, making play all but impossible.

The really weird thing is that the games in the queue the "require updating" are seemingly not downloading:

[image]

and my Settings > Downloads:

[image]

Right now the only way I can stop it from doing this is by quiting out of Steam entirely - something that's very bad for competitive CS:GO. And then it will just start doing it again a bit later.

Is this a known Steam bug or do I have something new? Or, preferably, how do I fix this?

Comment: Since the top image doesn't show Steam updating any of its games, the client is probably downloading (or uploading) something else, maybe the client itself, cloud synchronization or some meta data. Also check the download settings in the property page for for CS:GO specifically. It's possible override the default setting and allow downloads when playing specific games.

Comment: Is 16KB/s the correct setting for your equipment? That's .01 megabits, slightly faster than a 56K modem.

Comment: Have you set up permissions for broadcasting? Someone could be watching your game.

Comment: @Yorik I was trying to make it stop since it seemed to not be listening to my setting of the don't download while playing a game setting. And, no, I don't think I have set that.

Comment: Run Resmon before playing and alt-tab to check the network throughput when this happens. One thing I know affects pings in e.g. Left4Dead2 is servers with flash and ads in the MOTD. They can be grabbing bandwidth even when the MOTD is not showing. (pinion servers)

Comment: That does not seems like Steam's fault, but an external program fault. If you tell Steam to leave your internet alone while you play, it will comply. In fact that is actually the default setting. __Edit__: nevermind, just checked the first screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

You can disable the download inside steam while your playing. This can be activated in your options. I would suggest to enable this option always. You'll forget it otherwise on MP games. ;-)

Comment: I mentioned that I have this setting set in the question, thanks anyways.

Comment: But, as I see... your steam client doesn't load anything? It just says that an update is required?

Comment: Nope, I just uses up bandwidth and says that `update is required (not queued)`. The `(not queued)` part tells me that it shouldn't be downloading anything. However, it is.

Comment: Did you analyze if it's really downloading? The display in the upper left is sometimes buggy and counts kb but the network doesn't do anything.